# "d3.select(...) is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Just started D3 and I get an error in my console saying, "d3.select(...) is not a function".

I am not sure if it is because I am chaining functions or some other funky reason. I am using v5  of D3. It exists in the body of my HTML code.

Also, this is code from my instructor and theirs works fine. Any comments or help are appreciated!

javascript code

```
//define canvas area and margins
//svg container
var svgHeight = 1000;
var svgWidth = 1000;

//define margins
var margins = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
};
//create chart dims
var chartheight = svgHeight - margins.top - margins.bottom;
var chartWidth = svgWidth - margins.right - margins.left;

//create svg container
**var svg = d3.select("#scatter").append("svg")
.attr("height", svgHeight)
.atrr("width", svgWidth);** < --------------------------where the error gets thrown


// reading data from csv
data = d3.csv("./assets/data/data.csv")
console.log(data);
```

Comment: How are you importing d3? Make sure you are actually using "import d3" and not "from d3 import ..." or "import d3-path", as the latter two will not actually import d3.select

Comment: Make sure this js file is loaded before you d3 library script

Answer (score 1):

You're not spelling the second `.attr()` right.

Should be `attr()` instead of `atrr()`

See an example without errors below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    
    <!--<script src="LINK TO YOUR EXTERNAL JS FILE COMES BELOW"></script>-->
</head>
   
<body>   
    <p id="scatter">Some Element</p>
</body>

<script>
  var svgHeight = 1000;
  var svgWidth = 1000;

  var margins = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
  };

  var chartheight = svgHeight - margins.top - margins.bottom;
  var chartWidth = svgWidth - margins.right - margins.left;

  var svg = d3.select("#scatter")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("height", svgHeight)
            .attr("width", svgWidth);


// reading data from csv
// data = d3.csv("./assets/data/data.csv")
// console.log(data);
</script>
     
</html>
```

Comment: Very strange, this should be the right answer. 

Note: You misspelled "Element" in the `<p>` tag as "Elemennt"